# How much of a bonus do I get if I sell a specific number

Tags: if-statement

I have specific range in which I can get specific bonus. I tried this formula:

```
=IF(AND(J7>0,J7<30000),"0",IF(AND(J7>=30000,J7<60000),"500",IF(AND(J7>=60000,J7<125000),"1000", IF(AND(J7>=125000,J7<250000),"1500", IF(J7>=250000), "2000")
```

but it did not work. Bonus is defined as:

- less than 30000 I get 0
- 30000(included)-60000(not included) I get 500
- 60000(included)-125000(not included) I get 1000
- 125000(included)- 250000(not included) I get 1500
- 250000(included) and more I get 2000

Comment: What kind of formula is this? Please add a tag for its language/environment. And please elaborate on "it didn't work".